# Python: Find the shortest distance to get to another index in a list assuming you can go backwards

Tags: python, algorithm, list, shortest-path

How would you find the shortest path between letters in a list, assuming you can go backwards and end up on the other side of the list, Pacman Style

```
letters = ['a', 'd', 'e', 'l', 's']
letters.loopDistance('a', 's')
```

Returns 1

```
letters.loopDistance('a', 'l')
```

Returns 2

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: Can the same letter appear more than once in `letters`?

Comment: @Warren, I don't believe so.  Will have to check.

Answer (score 3):

Find the forward distance (wrapping around if necessary). If that's more than half the length of the list, then going the other direction will involve a shorter distance, which you can immediately compute by subtracting from the list length.

Things are a bit more complicated if the letters can appear more than once, mainly because it's ambiguous what you'd want as an answer.

Comment: Correct.  Just thought of this.

Answer (score 0):

```
def distance(l, first, second):
    ifirst = l.index(first)
    isecond = l.index(second)
    return min((ifirst - isecond) % len(l), (isecond - ifirst) % len(l))
```

Basically, you measure the distance in both directions and choose the smallest.